# Find whether user has signed in before

Tags: firebase-authentication

Firebase Authenticaiton allows users to sign in with a provider, like Google or Facebook.

However, if the user has never signed in before with a given provider, a new user account is generated for them automatically, and they are immediately signed in.

This is problematic for two reasons.

First, the developer may want to run some code on the server *before* the new user is signed in, such as preparing documents in the database for the user.

Second, the user may previously have signed in to the site with a provider account, but cannot remember which one they used. If the account they choose to sign in with has not been signed in with before, it would be useful to display a confirmation dialogue to the user to confirm that they wish to create a new account in the site. In some cases, the user may decide not to, and may try another account, to find the account they previously logged in with.

So, is there a way to have the user go through the usual OAuth flow, select a user to sign in with, determine whether they have signed in with it before, display a confirmation if they haven't, and then, if they confirm, create the user, or if the account already exists, and sign them in?

So, is there a way to have the following flow?

1. User chooses an account with the usual Google OAuth flow.
2. If the account is already registered with the site, it signs in.
3. If the account is not registered with the site, the user is asked to confirm that they wish to create a new account.
4. If the user wants to create a new account, the new account is created and other operations are conducted on the database, like preparing certain database documents for the new user.
5. Once the new account is created, the user is signed in to it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sign in methods return a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) object, which contains [AdditionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.AdditionalUserInfo) object. You can check isNewUser attribute from additionalUserInfo object.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had explored this approach before. However, unfortunately, by the time this method can be invoked, the new user has already been created and signed in. My desire is to be able to check whether the user already exists or not without creating it, and, depending upon the user choice, potentially never create it.

Comment: @ChrisTalman I think you can build your own implementation using fetchProvidersForEmail method. Given a email a address, get the registered providers, if no, ask user to confirm they want to create a new account.